# d3.mouse(this) return Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a bar+line+symbol chart that transforms when users click y axis to toggle between linear and sqrt. http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9457536. it works fine with one svg but when there are more than one svg in one webpage this can work on only one of svg(s); on the rest svg(s) the lines and symbols are moved to one single point because the x values are not a number. debugging shows d3.mouse(invisibleRect.node()) get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null. I'm suspicious this is related to priority of latest element when there are more than one svg elements on one page, but just struggling for a good solution. thanks.

```
d3.csv("data13.csv", function (error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  if (data.length == 0) {
    svg.append("text").text("data is empty");
    throw "No Input";
  }

  var attributeName = d3.keys(data[0])[0];
  var metricList = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
  var target = metricList[metricList.length - 1];

  data.forEach(function (d) {
    var maxData = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d3.max(metricList.map(function (name) { return +d[name]; })); });
    var minData = d3.min(data, function (d) { return d3.min(metricList.map(function (name) { return +d[name]; })); });

    x0.domain(metricList);
    x1.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d[attributeName]; })).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
    y.domain([Math.min(0, minData) * space_to_top, Math.max(0, maxData) * space_to_top]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    var drawBars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
      .data(metricList)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bargroup")
      .attr("transform", function (name) { return "translate(" + x0(name) + ",0)"; });

    drawBars.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function (metricName) {
        return data.map(function (d) {
          return {
            name: d[attributeName],
            value: +d[metricName],
            title: metricName
          };
        });
      })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function (d) { return y(Math.max(0, d.value)); })
      .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.abs(y(d.value) - y(0)); })
      .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.name); })
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.name));
      })
      .append("title")
      .text(function (d) {
        return attributeName + ": " + d.name
          + "\nCategory: " + d.title
          + "\nValue: " + d.value;
      });

    data.forEach(function (d, i) {
      var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (k) { return x0(k) + x1(d[attributeName]) + x1.rangeBand() / 2; })
        .y(function (k) { return y(+d[target]); });

      svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "targetLine" + i)
        .attr("d", lineFunction(metricList))
        .style("stroke", "#959595")
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

      // create symbols along the line
      svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(metricList)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "symbol" + i)
        .attr("transform", function (k) {
          return "translate(" + (x0(k) + x1(d[attributeName]) + x1.rangeBand() / 2) + ","
            + y(+d[target]) + ")";
        })
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
          .type(symbol(d[attributeName]))
          .size(64))
        .style("fill", color(d[attributeName]))
        .style("stroke", "000000")
        .on("mouseover", function (k) {
          d3.select(this).attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(symbol(d[attributeName])).size(180));
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (k) {
          d3.select(this).attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(symbol(d[attributeName])).size(64));
        })
        .append("title")
        .text(target + " for " + d[attributeName] + ": " + d[target]);
    });
    // toggle between linear and sqrt y axis

    var sqrtScale = d3.scale.sqrt().clamp(true).range([height, 0]);
    sqrtScale.domain([
      Math.min(0, minData) * space_to_top, 
      Math.max(0, maxData) * space_to_top
    ]);

    var sqrtAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(sqrtScale).orient('left');
    var log = false;
    var transitionDuration = 500;

    var lineFunction_sqrt = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function (k) { return x0(k) + x1(data[i][attributeName]) + x1.rangeBand() / 2; })
      .y(function (k) { return sqrtScale(+data[i][target]); });

    var lineFunction_linear = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function (k) { return x0(k) + x1(data[i][attributeName]) + x1.rangeBand() / 2; })
      .y(function (k) { return y(+data[i][target]); });

    invisibleRect = svg.append('rect')
      .attr({
        'x': -margin.left,
        'y': 0,
        'height': height,
        'width': margin.left,
        'fill': '#FFFFFF',
        'opacity': 0.0,
        'id': 'invisibleRect'
      });

    invisibleRect.on('click', function () {
      try {
        hoverHelp.remove();
      }
      catch (ReferenceError) {
        console.log("There's no hoverHelp right now.");
      }
      if (!log) {
        svg.select('.y.axis')
          .transition()
          .duration(transitionDuration)
          .call(sqrtAxis);
        drawBars.selectAll("rect")
          .transition()
          .duration(transitionDuration)
          .attr("y", function (d) { return sqrtScale(Math.max(0, d.value)); })
          .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.abs(sqrtScale(d.value) - sqrtScale(0)); });

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          svg.select(".targetLine" + i)
            .transition()
            .duration(transitionDuration)
            .attr("d", lineFunction_sqrt(metricList, i));
        };

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          svg.selectAll(".symbol" + i)
            .transition()
            .duration(transitionDuration)
            .attr("transform", function (k) {
              return "translate(" + (x0(k) + x1(data[i][attributeName]) + x1.rangeBand() / 2) + ","
                + sqrtScale(+data[i][target]) + ")";
            });
        };

        log = true;

      } else {
        svg.select('.y.axis')
          .transition()
          .duration(transitionDuration)
          .call(yAxis);

        drawBars.selectAll("rect")
          .transition()
          .duration(transitionDuration)
          .attr("y", function (d) { return y(Math.max(0, d.value)); })
          .attr("height", function (d) { return Math.abs(y(d.value) - y(0)); });

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          svg.select(".targetLine" + i)
            .transition()
            .duration(transitionDuration)
            .attr("d", lineFunction_linear(metricList, i));
         };

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          svg.selectAll(".symbol" + i)
            .transition()
            .duration(transitionDuration)
            .attr("transform", function (k) {
              return "translate(" + (x0(k) + x1(data[i][attributeName]) + x1.rangeBand() / 2) + ","
                + y(+data[i][target]) + ")";
            });
        };

        log = false;
      }
    });

    invisibleRect.on('mouseover', function () {
      debugger;
      var coords = d3.mouse(invisibleRect.node());
      var hoverHelp = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'hoverHelp');

      var x = coords[0];
      var y = coords[1];

      var triangleSize = 25;
      var rectWidth = 200;
      var rectHeight = 50;

      hoverHelp.append('polygon')
        .attr({
          'fill': '#3F0040',
          'opacity': 0.5,
          'points': x + ',' + y + ' ' + (x + triangleSize) + ',' + (y - triangleSize) + ' ' + (x + triangleSize + rectWidth) + ',' + (y - triangleSize) + ' ' + (x + triangleSize + rectWidth) + ',' + (y - triangleSize + rectHeight) + ' ' + (x + triangleSize) + ',' + (y - triangleSize + rectHeight) + ' ' + (x + triangleSize) + ',' + (y + triangleSize),
          'stroke-width': 3,
          'stroke': '#FD00FF',
          'stroke-linecap': 'round'
        });

      hoverHelp.append('text')
        .attr({
          'x': x + triangleSize + rectWidth / 2,
          'y': y - triangleSize + rectHeight / 2,
          'text-anchor': 'middle',
          'dominant-baseline': 'central',
          'fill': '#FFFFFF',
          'text-weight': 'bold'
        })
        .text('Click to toggle axis.');
    });

    invisibleRect.on('mouseout', function () {
      try {
        hoverHelp.remove();
      } catch (ReferenceError) {
        console.log("There's no hoverHelp right now.");
      }
    });
```